Trigamma-free Negative Binomial regression: doubts on Hessian and Fisher Information Matrix in the dispersion parameter
I have been looking at alternative versions of the Hessian and Fisher (expected) Information Matrix for the Negative Binomial regression specification, which are given by widely-cited academic sources on the topic, specifically Hilbe (2011); Cameron and Trivedi (2013); and Lawless (1987). I sense that there might be imprecisions in the cited literature due to how different sources handle the Gamma function (typically under the hood, as computations are rarely specified in full). Yet I wonder if there are flaws in how I reach my conclusions. Details are provided below - feedback, hints and corrections are greatly appreciated.
Issue 1: Hessian in the dispersion parameter
I begin from the Negative Binomial specification derived from a Poisson cross-section regression, as illustarted by Greene (2014: p.847):
$$y_i \sim \mathrm{Neg.Bin}\left(\lambda_i, \alpha \right) \equiv \mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right)= \frac{\Gamma\left( y_i + \alpha \right)}{\Gamma\left( y_i + 1 \right) \Gamma\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \alpha}\right)^{y_i}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_i + \alpha}\right)^\alpha$$
where $y_i$ is the $i-$th observation of the count variable of interest, $\lambda_i=e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ is the conditional mean or link function, a function of the vector of regression coefficients $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and the vector of regressors for the $i-$th observation $\mathbf{x}_i$; and $\alpha$ is the gamma scale (or shape) parameter which typically models the unobservable disturbance.
Building on the above notation I obtain the following "gamma-free" log-likelihood in the "dispersion" parameter $\theta = \alpha^{-1}$ as in  Cameron and Trivedi (2013: p.81):
$$
\begin{equation}  
\ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\theta \right) =\sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\ln\left( j + \theta^{-1}  \right) - \ln\left( y_i! \right) + y_i\mathbf{x}_i^T\boldsymbol{\beta} + y_i\ln\theta -\left( \theta^{-1} + y_i\right)\ln\left(1+\theta e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) \right\}  \tag{1}\label{maxlik}
\end{equation}
$$
where I use the result: $\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i + \alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)}=\prod_{j=1}^{y_i-1}\left( j+\alpha\right)$, following Lawless (1987:p.210).
Nothing new until this point. Notice that Equation \eqref{maxlik} corresponds (after some algebra) to Eq.8.9 in Hilbe (2011:p.190), except that the latter retains the natural logarithm of the Gamma function.
I now move on to differentiating Equation \eqref{maxlik} with respect to the dispersion parameter $\theta$:
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\theta \right)}{\partial \theta} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{-\frac{1}{\theta^2}\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\theta^{-1}} + \frac{y_i}{\theta} + \frac{1}{\theta^2}\ln\left( 1+\theta e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) -\left(\theta^{-1} + y_i \right)\frac{e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}}}{\left( 1+\theta e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)}\right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\theta^2} \left[ -\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\theta^{-1}} + \ln\left( 1+\theta e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)  \right] + \frac{y_i \left(  1+\theta e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}} \right) - \theta \left( \theta^{-1}+y_i\right)e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}} }{\theta\left(  1+\theta e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}} \right)} \right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\theta^2} \left[ -\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\theta^{-1}} + \ln\left( 1+\theta \lambda_i\right)  \right] + \frac{y_i-\lambda_i}{\theta\left( 1 + \theta\lambda_i\right)}\right\}  \tag{2}\label{d1}
\end{align}
$$
which corresponds to Eq.3.29 in Cameron and Trivedi (2013: p.81). I won't dwell on the differences between Equation \eqref{d1} and its counterparts in Hilbe (2011: p.192); and Lawless (1987: p.211).
Continuing with the first-order conditions, the second derivative of Equation \eqref{maxlik} (or, equivalently, the fist derivative of Equation \eqref{d1}) with respect to $\theta$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial^2 \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\theta \right)}{\partial \theta^2} & = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{2j\theta+1}{\theta^2\left(j\theta+1\right)^2} + \left[ \frac{ \frac{\theta\lambda_i}{\left(1+\theta \lambda_i\right)} - 2\ln \left(1+\theta \lambda_i\right) }{\theta^3} - \left(y_i - \lambda_i \right)\frac{\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\theta^2\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)^2} \right] \right\} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\theta^2} \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{\theta\left(2j+\theta^{-1}\right)}{\theta^2\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2} + \frac{1}{\theta^2}\left[ \frac{\theta\lambda_i-\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)2\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\theta\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)} - \frac{\left(y_i-\lambda_i\right)\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)^2} \right]  \right\} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\theta^3} \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2} - \frac{1}{\theta^3}\left[\frac{\theta\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)\left(y_i-\lambda_i\right)-\theta\lambda_i\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)^2}+2\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right) \right]  \right\} \tag{3}\label{d2}
\end{align}
$$
This is where the trouble begins since none of the cited references can be used to directly verify Equation \eqref{d2}. The closest result is Eq.8.18 in Hilbe (2011: p.192) which, however, features the trigramma function $\psi^{'}\left( \cdot \right)$ that is, the derivative of the digamma function $\psi\left( \cdot \right)=\frac{\Gamma^{'}\left( \cdot \right)}{\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)}$.
It is worth showing that the alternative gradient and Hessian I would have obtained, had I started from a different version of Equation \eqref{maxlik} in which the Gamma function is retained, correspond indeed to Eqs.8.14 and 8.18, respectively, in Hilbe (2011: p.192):
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\theta \right)}{\partial \theta} &=\sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \frac{1}{\theta^2}\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right)+\frac{y_i-\lambda_i}{\theta\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)} +  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i + \theta^{-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\theta^{-1}\right)} \right]  \right\} \nonumber \\ 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \frac{1}{\theta^2}\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right)+\frac{y_i-\lambda_i}{\theta\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)} + \left[ \psi\left(y_i + \theta^{-1}\right) - \psi\left(\theta^{-1}\right) \right] \right\}  \tag{4}\label{d1b}
\end{align}
$$
where $\psi\left( \cdot \right)$ is the digamma function. Taking the derivative of Equation \eqref{d1b} yields a version of Equation \eqref{d2} which now features the trigamma function $\psi^{'}\left(\cdot\right)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\theta \right)}{\partial \theta^2} &=\sum_{i=1}^n \left\{  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \frac{1}{\theta^2}\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{y_i-\lambda_i}{\theta\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)} + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2}\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i+\theta^{-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\theta^{-1}\right)}\right] \right\} \nonumber \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ - \frac{1}{\theta^3}\left[\frac{\theta\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)\left(y_i-\lambda_i\right)-\theta\lambda_i\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)^2}+2\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right) \right] + \left[\psi^{'}\left(y_i + \theta^{-1}\right) - \psi^{'}\left(\theta^{-1}\right) \right]\right\} \tag{5}\label{d2b}
\end{align}
$$
I now compare Equations \eqref{d1} and \eqref{d2} with Equations \eqref{d1b} and \eqref{d2b}, respectively, and conclude that, when the log-likelihood is expressed in terms of $\theta$ (not the gamma scale parameter $\alpha$) the following equivalences hold:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i+\theta^{-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\theta^{-1}\right)}\right]=\left[\psi\left(y_i + \theta^{-1}\right) - \psi\left(\theta^{-1}\right)  \right]=-\frac{1}{\theta^2}\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\theta^{-1}} \tag{6}\label{diga}$$ and $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2}\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i+\theta^{-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\theta^{-1}\right)}\right]=\left[\psi^{'}\left(y_i + \theta^{-1}\right) - \psi^{'}\left(\theta^{-1}\right)  \right]=\frac{1}{\theta^3}\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1} \right)^2} \tag{7}\label{triga} $$
Now I am aware of the following, slightly different results that can be obtained if one considers the gamma scale parameter $\alpha$ instead of $\theta$ - see e.g., Yu et al. (2024):
\begin{align}
\psi\left({y + \alpha}\right) - \psi\left({\alpha}\right) &= \sum_{j=0}^{y-1}\frac{1}{j+\alpha}   \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j + \theta^{-1}}\tag{8}\label{diga2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
 \psi^{'}\left({y + \alpha}\right) - \psi^{'}\left({\alpha}\right) &= -\sum_{j=0}^{y-1}\frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2} \nonumber \\
&= -\sum_{j=0}^{y-1}\frac{1}{\left(j +\theta^{-1}\right)^2} \tag{9}\label{triga2}
\end{align}
Comparing Equations \eqref{diga} and \eqref{triga} with Equations \eqref{diga2} and \eqref{triga2} I cannot help but wonder: have I done something wrong in my derivation process?
The reason for asking is that, in practice, Equations \eqref{diga2} and \eqref{triga2} (which are given in the gamma parameter $\alpha$), seem to be invoked "as is" in the literature when obtaining expressions for gradient and Hessian (which are given in the disperion parameter). See for example Eq.2.8 in Lawless (1987: p.211); and Eq.3.32 in Cameron and Trivedi (2013: p.81).
Issue #2: Fisher Information Matrix
The issue discussed above spills over into calculating the Fisher Information Matrix i.e., the expectations of minus the second derivatives. I will now focus on one element of the Fisher Information Matrix, namely the expected value of minus the (trigamma-free) second derivative obtained in Equation \eqref{d2}:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left[-\frac{\partial^2 \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\theta \right)}{\partial \theta^2}\right] &= \frac{1}{\theta^3} \sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[\frac{\theta\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)\left(y_i-\lambda_i\right)-\theta\lambda_i\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)^2}+2\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right) - \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2} \right]\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\theta^3} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[\frac{ 2\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right)^2 \ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right) - \theta\lambda_i\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right)- \theta\lambda_i\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\left(1+\theta\lambda_i \right)^2 } -\sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr}\left(y_i\right)  \right]+\frac{1}{\theta^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta\frac{\left(1+2\theta\lambda_i\right)}{\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)^2}\mathrm{E}\left[y_i\right]  \\
&=\frac{1}{\theta^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\left[2\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)-\frac{\theta\lambda_i}{1+\theta\lambda_i}-\sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr}\left(y_i\right) \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{\theta^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\left[2\ln\left(1+\theta\lambda_i\right)-\frac{\theta\lambda_i}{1+\theta\lambda_i}-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y \geq j \right) \right] \tag{10}\label{fish} \\
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right)$ is the Negative Binomial probability density function defined at the very beginning; $\mathrm{E}\left[y_i\right]=\sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty} y_i\mathrm{Pr}\left(y_i\right)$ is the expected value of $y_i$.
My main concern is about how I arrive the identity $\sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1} \frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr}\left(y_i\right)  = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j +\theta^{-1}\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y \geq j \right) $ in Equation \eqref{fish}. Specifically, I follow Yu et al. (2024)  (p.16, appendix), except that I invoke Equations \eqref{diga} and \eqref{triga} above, to obtain the expected value of the trigamma function expressed in the dispersion parameter $\theta$ as follows:
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{E}\left[ \psi^{'}\left(y_i + \theta^{-1} \right)\right] - \psi^{'}\left(\theta^{-1}\right) &= \sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty}\left[ \psi^{'}\left(y_i + \theta^{-1} \right) - \psi^{'}\left(\theta^{-1} \right)\right]\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\theta^3}\sum_{y_i=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right)\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{\theta^3} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2} \sum_{y_i=j+1}^{\infty} \mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{\theta^3} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2j+\theta^{-1}}{\left(j+\theta^{-1}\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr}\left(Y \geq j\right)
\end{align}
I wonder which one is correct, Equation \eqref{fish} above or the versions given in the literature? Take, for example, the argument within brackets in Eq.3.32 in Cameron and Trivedi (2013: p.81). Am I wrong in sensing that it has been obtained from computing the "observed" information matrix (i.e., minus the second  derivative of the loglikelihood function, without taking the expectation), and then applying Equation \eqref{triga2}, which is developed with respect to the gamma scale parameter $\alpha$?

The quickest way to double check is to do a numerical comparison. With many numerical differentiation routines available, doing some simulation is straightforward.

@ZackFisher you have indeed a good point. Yet I admit I am more concerned about the process of deriving those expressions, than their final outcome. The reason being figuring out whether I have a leg to stand on when arguing that there might be a slight, yet not inconsequential "abuse of notation" cemented, as it were, in well-established and widely referenced work.

At the risk of making this look like a pretentious solipsism, I thought I'd attempt a heads up - if anything to share some additional evidence I wasn't aware of at the time of posting, but might help better articulate what I couldn't quite put my finger on a month or so ago.
If the proof is in the proverbial pudding, then it isn't perhaps surprising that, when it comes to parameters other than the vector of regression coefficients, the clearest expressions for the Negative Binomial regression's gradient and Hessian are not to be found in the widely-cited resources I've been commenting on. Instead, these useful expressions are buried in the scripts of the celebrated $\texttt{MASS}$ package for the statistical computing language $\texttt{R}$.
Specifically, I start just as in the original question i.e. from the pdf: $ y_i \sim \mathrm{Neg.Bin}\left(\lambda_i, \alpha \right) \equiv \mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i | \lambda_i,\alpha\right) $. Except that, this time, I re-sate the log-likelihood in the gamma scale parameter $\alpha$ (not the dispersion parmeter $\theta$):
\begin{equation}
\ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha\right) =\sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \left[\ln\Gamma\left(y_i + \alpha\right) - \ln\Gamma\left(\alpha\right) + \ln\left(y!\right) \right]+ y_i\ln\lambda_i + \alpha\ln\alpha - \left(\alpha + y_i\right)\ln\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right) \right\}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_i = e^{\mathbf{x}_i^T\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function. Starting from the loglikelihood, the trick that sets the $\texttt{MASS}$ approach apart from the rest of the sources I've cited couldn't be simpler: leave the gamma scale parameter $\alpha$ alone instead of insisting on using its reciprocal, the dispersion parameter $\theta=\alpha^{-1}$ (although, ironically, the scripts call the parameter in question theta...).
Differentiating $\ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha\right)$ with respect to $\alpha$ yields:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha \right)}{\partial \alpha} & = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \left[\psi\left(y_i+\alpha\right) - \psi\left(\alpha\right) + \left( \ln\alpha + 1\right) \right] - \left[\ln\left(\lambda_i + \alpha \right) + \frac{\alpha}{\left( \lambda_i + \alpha \right)} \right] - \frac{y_i}{\left( \lambda_i + \alpha \right)}  \right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n  \left\{ \left[  \psi\left(y_i+\alpha\right) - \psi\left(\alpha\right) \right]+ \ln\alpha + 1 - \ln\left(\lambda_i + \alpha \right) - \frac{\left( \alpha + y_i \right)}{\left( \lambda_i + \alpha \right)} \right\}
\end{align}
where $\psi(\cdot)=\frac{\Gamma^{'}
(\cdot)}{\Gamma(\cdot)}$ is the digamma function. Now that the argument of the digamma function is $\alpha$, establishing a link with the "digamma-free" notation becomes neater (as before I follow this source ):
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i+\alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)}\right]=\left[\psi\left(y_i + \alpha \right) - \psi\left(\alpha \right) \right]=\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\alpha} 
\end{equation}
meaning that the gradient with respect to $\alpha$ can be re-expressed in a digamma-free form as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha \right)}{\partial \alpha} & = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\alpha} + \ln\alpha + 1 - \ln\left(\lambda_i + \alpha \right) - \frac{\left( \alpha + y_i \right)}{\left( \lambda_i + \alpha \right)}   \right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\alpha}  - \ln\left(1 + \alpha^{-1}\lambda_i \right) - \frac{y_i-\lambda_i}{\alpha\left(1+\alpha^{-1}\lambda_i\right)}   \right\}
\end{align}
What other references seem to do, instead, is a slight, yet not inconsequential abuse of notation: in a context where likelihood, gradient and hessian equations are expressed in the dispersion parameter $\theta$, what is commonly referred to as $\left[\psi\left(y_i + \theta^{-1} \right) - \psi\left(\theta^{-1} \right) \right]$ is, in fact, a derivative with respect to $\alpha$. This potential confusion is, I argue, swept under the carpet, as it were, the moment in which $\theta^{-1}$ is swiftly substituted for $\alpha$ in $\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{j+\alpha}$.
The same goes for the Hessian:
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial^2 \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha \right)}{\partial \alpha^2} & = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \psi^{'}\left(y_i + \alpha\right) - \psi^{'}\left(\alpha\right) + \frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right)} - \frac{\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right)-\left(y_i + \alpha\right)}{\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right)^2}  \right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ \psi^{'}\left(y_i + \alpha\right) - \psi^{'}\left(\alpha\right) + \frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{2}{\lambda_i + \alpha} - \frac{y_i + \alpha}{\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right)^2} \right\} 
\end{align}
where $\psi^{'}$ is the derivative of the digamma function i.e., the trigamma function. Also in this case, thanks to the parameterisation in $\alpha$, the link with the ``trigamma'' free version (again following this source ) is also neater:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha^2}\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(y_i+\alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)}\right]=\left[\psi^{'}\left({y_i + \alpha}\right) - \psi^{'}\left({\alpha}\right)\right] = -\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2}
\end{equation}
meaning that the Hessian may be re-written in a trigamma-free form as follow:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha \right)}{\partial \alpha^2} & = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{  -\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{2}{\lambda_i + \alpha} - \frac{y_i + \alpha}{\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right)^2}  \right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{ -\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2}  + \frac{\lambda_i^2+\alpha y_i}{\alpha\left(\alpha+\lambda_i\right)^2} \right\}
\end{align}
The above results can be verified taking a closer look at the relevant $\texttt{MASS}$ scripts. However, it is not possible to verify the relevant Fisher information matrix element because, as specified in the relvant documentation, $\texttt{MASS}$ relies on the "observed" information for the MLE of $\alpha$.
Nevertheless, it is possible to build on the previous results and at least have a stab a the expected information, with the caveat that I might still be wrong:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left[-\frac{\partial^2 \ln L\left(\boldsymbol{\beta},\alpha \right)}{\partial \alpha^2}\right] & = \sum_{i=1}^n\left\{  -\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{2}{\lambda_i + \alpha} - \frac{\alpha}{\left( \lambda_i + \alpha \right)^2} - \frac{1}{\left(\lambda_i + \alpha\right)^2} \sum_{y_i=0}^\infty y_i \mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right) + \sum_{y_i=0}^\infty  \mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right)\sum_{j=0}^{y_i-1}\frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2}  \right\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n\left\{   -\frac{1}{\alpha}  + \frac{1}{\lambda_i + \alpha} + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr\left(Y\right)>j} \right\} 
\end{align}
where I have invoked $y_i \mathrm{Pr}\left(Y=y_i\right)=\textrm{E}\left[y_i\right]=\lambda_i$, and the theorem in this reference: $\textrm{E}\left[\psi^{'}\left(y_i+\alpha\right)\right]-\psi^{'}\left(\alpha\right)=-\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(j+\alpha\right)^2}\mathrm{Pr\left(Y>j\right)}$
